# css link not making all text a link?

Tags: html, css

I have dropdown menu and its made via a list and position absolute, however the dropdown links are very very very small area and do not cover the text completely.

How can I fix this?

Example http://outreviews.com/v%202/index.html (the dropdown menus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add:

```
ul li a {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

It should work okay, and since even IE allows `display: inline-block;` on natively in-line elements it should be relatively cross-browser friendly (certainly under a valid doctype).

It's worth remembering that `padding` on the parent `li` will also reduce the possible width of the child `a` element, and the `display: inline` on the same parent `li` is also likely to cause you a *little* trouble (since `display: block;` on the `a` would be so much simpler).

---

Edited to note that [@Chris Bentley correctly noted the points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113286/css-link-not-making-all-text-a-link/4113326#4113326)  in my final paragraph (above the `hr`) just prior to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from the sub menu's UL and LI and give the A element "display:block" This will make the A element take up the entire width of the menu.

You can fiddle with the padding to get it the way you want it.

Comment: He has the LI set to display:inline, so putting a block element in there will ruin everything.

Comment: thanks @Robusto. ..and remove the display:inline from the LI.

Comment: there's always `display:inline-block;` for cases where neither inline nor block quite do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes:

in `#headermenu li` change the `padding:20px;` to `padding :0 20px;`

add delete the `top:55px;` from `#headermenu li ul`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make the li elements `display:list-item` and the a elements `display:block`. That's what's being done on the site you're linking to.